# MVC4 + jQuery fade out notification div

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm really new to using JavaScript and JQuery and I need some help clearing up a simple problem I am having.

I am loading the below div dynamically depending on the result of a save to the database and want the user notification to fade out after a second or two. The script I have compiles and runs without issues but does not fade out the div.

Can you let me know what I'm missing or if there is a better way to do this.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(IList<Datapoint> model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            ctx.SaveChanges(model);
            ViewBag.Notification = "Save Successful";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Notification = "Save Failed";
        }               
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

**Html**

```
@if(!ViewBag.Notification.ToString().Equals(string.Empty))
{
    <div id="Notification" class="large-4 large-offset-6 columns"> 
        <h5 class="button [secondary success alert] round">@ViewBag.Notification.ToString()</h5>
    </div>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("Notification").fadeOut(1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `#` before id selector

```
<script>
    $("#Notification").fadeOut(1000);
    //.^...........
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that one.